# Reactjs Datatable Change Text

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-data-table-component

I'm using react-data-table-component.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component

[image]

There is a structure that works completely with or without data in the table. However, my question is in the text shown by default when there is no data.

[image]

My only goal is to change the text 'There are no records to display' written here.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change it.
Documentation available on given link provided by you.
[image: DOCUMENTATION]

Code (Sample 1)

```
<DataTable
    title="Tables"
    noDataComponent={"No records"}
    columns={[1, 2, 3]}
  />
```

Code(Sample 2)

```
<DataTable
    title="Tables"
    noDataComponent={<b>No Records</b>}
    columns={[1, 2, 3]}
  />
```